Android Emulator unable to connect
I am running an app but after the gradle is built it is taking way too long to connect to emulator and after 5 minutes it is showing : "Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online." The emulator is for Pixel 7 android 14.0.
Please help
I had tried to delete the emulator files under AVD and reinstalled it but i am still getting the same problem
